# Failed sp_executesql queries and rpc_completed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, monitoring, extended-events

I'd like to track which procedures are failing in my database using extended events. Procedures are being executed like that from an application:

```
EXEC sp_executesql 'exec dbo.GetData';
```

And when that fails, I expect to capture XE event of `rpc_completed` with `result = 1` (failure) but it comes with `result = 0`

My procedures look like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetData
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 1/0 AS DivisionByZero;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXECUTE dbo.LogError;
        THROW;
    END CATCH
END
```

Is there some sort of configuration that needs to happen to track failed `rpc_completed` events or I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you try capturing the exception event and then can match up the two events via the SPID?

Comment: That's what i actually do. I capture both of these and try to merge into one. But I don't want to capture every single rpc completed, that's the reason I filter by `result=1` which is supposed to mean failure